# Aligning Text with a RadioGroup/RadioButton

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to have text next to a RadioGroup that is a sort of label for it. So there are two buttons in the RadioGroup with text to them, and currently, I can only get the tops to align, but that looks pretty awkward. I can try to margin the TextView in line but that's not ideal or easy. The RadioGroup and TextView live inside a RelativeLayout, I've tried `android:layout_alignBaseline` for the TextView with the RadioGroup and one of the RadioButtons, but it doesn't seem that the RadioGroup has a baseline, and I can't seem to get the baseline for the RadioButton from the TextView.

Comment: I can't answer my question this early yet, but...If anyone else runs into this issue, it seems that you can move a TextView INTO the RadioGroup to resolve the issue. Maybe that's obvious to everyone else, but that doesn't seem semantically clear to me. So I thought I would share.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem these days and I finally solved it.
I tried every combination that came on my mind and in the end I figure it out that trick is in putting android:layout_weight with a same value on TextViews. That aligns them just on the center of RadioButtons.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_button"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    />
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_button"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/cop_radiobutton_label"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/thief_radiobutton_label"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/linearLayout5" 
           android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
           android:layout_height= "50dip"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:background="@drawable/squareback">

           <RadioGroup
               android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal" >

               <RadioButton
                   android:id="@+id/meleeRadio"
                   android:layout_width="150dip"
                   android:layout_height="40dip"
                   android:checked="false"
                   android:text="Melee Attack" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_margin="5dip"/>

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/rangeRadio"
               android:layout_width="150dip"
               android:layout_height="40dip"
               android:text="Range Attack" android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_margin="5dip" android:checked="false"/>

           </RadioGroup>



        </LinearLayout>
```

To align them I put them in a LinearLayout that I set a size for. Then I android:layout_gravity="center" which will align the center for the items. So even though the button and text are not the same size they look good imo.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I needed to have some text aligned to the center of a RadioGroup, that will serve as a label to the 3 RadioButtons.
I achieved it by setting the android:layout_gravity attribute on the textView to center.
Below is the code snippet:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Experience Level:"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

   <RadioGroup
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Novice"/>
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Intermidiate"/>
       <RadioButton
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Advanced"/>
   </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```